# Java Android issue: keyword -- new

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android. I am really confused about this problem. For example, there are two java files.

```
One.java
Two.java
```

I want to use some functions or parameters from Two.java, so I do this.

```
Two two = new Two();
two.something;
```

or either I can do like this:

```
public class One(){
  private Two two;
  public One(Context context){
    two = (Two) context;
  }
  public void func(){
    two.something;
  }
```

or maybe like:

```
public class One(){
  Two two;
  public void func(){
    two = new Two();
    two.something;
  }
}
```

What's the difference between these ways or are there any other ways? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Both of your examples of the class `One`, and instance of the class `One` contains an instance of the class `Two`.

If your first example (as @Serdar pointed out) two is null. You address that in your second example, but each time you call `func()` you replace the old `Two` with a new `Two`.

An alternate option would be to create an instance of `Two` in the constructor of `One`, especially if the constructor for `Two` requires parameters that could be passed to the constructor of `One`

```
public class One
{
    private Two two;

    public One()
    {
        two = new Two();
    }

    public void func()
    {
       two.something;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your two examples are doing something very different.

Let's consider example 1:

You have a private instance of class Two contained in class One. You cast an instance of Context into Two using the line `two=(Two)context;`
This will only work if context refers to an object of class Two or something that derives from Two. Moreover it will only work if Context itself is a base class of Two in the hierarchy. Otherwise you will get a ClassCastException.

Let's consider example 2:

By doing `two=new Two();` You are allocating a new instance of class Two. This is different from casting as you were doing in example 1 as there you assumed that an underlying instance of Two already existed in the form of context.
Also, the line `two.something;` will access a member 'something' of the class Two. It is not passing any parameters or calling any function. Depending on what something is (a function or data member) you can either call it in case of a function or assign to it.

Seems like you need to read Core Java.

Answer (score 0):

This is not Android specific, it's about the Java language. Since you're asking this question I assume you are also very new to Java. You'll want to check out the Java tutorials, in particular [Creating Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) in the [Classes and Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html) chapter. What you're doing in your second example, however, is a type cast, not an instantiation.

Welcome to Java! :)